# Treatments of Mahaney's Theorem?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Could you direct me to some readable treatments of Mahaney's theorem? The best thing I've been able to find is [Fortnow's lecture](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~fortnow/classes/f10/395-Complexity/Lecture3.pdf). I'm especially interested in discussion around the theorem and its ramifications. Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kozen's *Theory of Computation*, Theorem 29.2 ([on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=AolrsLBq3u0C&lpg=PA177&ots=OGX-72D3QM&pg=PA177#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Alan Selman (editor) *Complexity Theory Retrospective*, Theorem 5.2.1 ([on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vsc6DaHOP68C&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&source=bl&ots=rkIuLWW5QL&sig=XLgAOYGtRRVPWyNTkgq88HQCDC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=30WOT8O8Hc69gAfMpOz4DQ&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&f=false)).